# return value by document.getElementById("radio1").click()

Tags: javascript

I have this situation

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" onclick="clickRadio1()" />Click Radio1
<input type="radio" id="radio2" onclick="clickRadio2()" />Click Radio2 to activate Radio1 click
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function clickRadio1(){
        return false;
    }

    function clickRadio2(){
        if(document.getElementById("radio1").click===false){
            alert("False");
        }else{
            alert("True");
        }
    }

    // -->
</script>
```

When I click "radio2" why I always get alert "True". Can someone explain why? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why would it return anything else ?

Comment: As a sidenote, the onchange event would be more appropriate here.

Comment: `click`? You mean `checked`?

Answer (score 1):

Because the event name is `onclick` and not `click`.

Also make sure that your JavaScript script is running after the page is fully loaded by putting your code inside the loaded event of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try use,

```
document.getElementById("radio1").checked;


 function clickRadio2(){
    if(document.getElementById("radio1").checked===false){
        alert("False");
    }else{
        alert("True");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all comment. But no comment serve my purpose. My purpose is to click radio2 and have "radio1.checked = true", running and get the return value from function clickRadio1() at the same time. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This is working (changed the alert to a div result for jsFiddle)

### http://jsfiddle.net/zv49k/

You need to change the .click attribute to .checked for the radio button.

```
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" onclick="clickRadio1()" />Click Radio1
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" onclick="clickRadio2()" />Click Radio2
        <div id="resultdiv"></div>
        <script>
            function clickRadio1() {
                return false;
            }

            function clickRadio2() {
                if (!document.getElementById("radio1").checked) {
                    document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML = "False";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML = "True";
                }
            }
        </script>
```